# How to MVC 5 drop down (multiple select) box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble with this drop down box, just cant seem to get it right, here's the code:

View (Index.cshtml):

```
@using EvaSimulator.Models
@Model EvaSimulator.Models.ModelVariables
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    ModelVariables mv = new ModelVariables();
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("DropDownBox", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("dropdownbox", )
    <button type="submit"></button>
}
<p>@Model.dropDownList</p>
```

Model (ModelVariables.cs):

```
public string dropDownList = "";
```

Controller (HomeController.cs):

```
public ActionResult DropDownBox(string dropdownbox)
{
    ModelVariables mv = new ModelVariables();
    mv.dropDownList = dropdownbox;
    return this.View("Index", mv);
}
```

This just doesent look right, and I'm only looking for a simple solution, create a drop down multiple select list box and whatever I submit, I get the list of values and print them in `<p>` tag in the view (`@Model.dropDownList`)

Answer (score 6):

First you should add a new property to your view model class for the dropdown data of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. We will add a second property of array type(*since you want a multi select*) to hold the selected option values .

```
public class ModelVariables
{
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options {set;get;}
  public string[] SelectedOptions { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this view model,populate the `Options` property and send to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new ModelVariables();
  vm.Options = new List<SelectListItem> {
     new SelectListItem { Value="MI", Text="Michigan" },
     new SelectListItem { Value="NY", Text="New York" },
  };
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view ,use the `Html.ListBoxFor` helper method

```
@model ModelVariables
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   <label> Select items <label>
   @Html.ListBoxFor(s=>s.SelectedOptions,Model.Options)
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action, you can have the same view model as your method parameter and Model binder will be able to map the posted form data to an object of that. The selected options from the UI will be available in the `SelectedOptions` property of the view model object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ModelVariables model)
{
  // check model.SelectedOptions property value
 // to do : Return something
}
```

Comment: Hello Shyju, ran the code and it got an exception at 'There is no viewdata item of the type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedOptions'

Comment: The above code uses strongly typed model & it's properties to build the dropdown. There is no way you should get that error unless you are not using the code explained in the answer above.

Comment: I had all of this working but was trying to use `@Html.DropdownListFor` with `multiple = "multiple"` in the `htmlAttributes`, which didn't work. Switching to `@Html.ListBoxFor` was the key.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `For` helper instead to get compile time checking.
When using `MultiSelectList` we need to bind the selected values to an array in the first param, then you can pass your select list with the values to be shown in the second param.

```
 public string[] SelectedValues { get; set; }

 public MultiSelectList DropDownList { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
 mv.DropDownList = new MultiSelectList(/*Your list of items here*/)
```

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedValues, Model.DropDownList)
```

Comment: @Novastorm Great! This feels like so long ago when I posted this.