# Multi Select .Net MVC to single concatenated field for Entity Framework?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, input, controller, multi-select

I am combining a multi select form to a single input using JavaScript. But I am getting the input cut off using any delimiters. When the Controller gets the request I'm only getting the first item selected. I've checked to make sure the form variable is getting updated so I think it's the controller. What am I missing?

**View:**

[image]

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="updateservices">Update Services</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select name="updateservices" id="updateservices" multiple="true" rows="3">
                <option value="HCL">HCL</option>
                <option value="HCL2">HCL2</option>
                <option value="HBS">HBS</option>
            </select>
         </div>
        </div>

        $('#createform').submit(function () {
            console.log("test");
            // Combine service update tags
            var tags = $('#updateservices').val().join(',');
            $('#updateservices').attr('value', tags);
            console.log(tags);
            console.log($('#updateservices').attr('value'))
        });
```

With an output in the javascript console of:

HCL,HCL2

HCL,HCL2

**Controller**

```
 // POST: PatchesMVC/Create
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "PatchID, updateservices] Patch patch)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(patch.updateservices);
        }
```

With an output of:

HCL

**UPDATE**

Including Headers from Post. There are more form fields included in this as I didn't want to post the code for the whole form. I'm not seeing the `Request Payload` containing the `#updatedservices` field.

Post from Network Tab Headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:59515/PatchesMVC/Create/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:59515
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:438
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 02 Aug 2017 17:01:05 GMT
Location:/PatchesMVC
Persistent-Auth:true
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.2
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcYmlqZW5raW5zXERvY3VtZW50c1xWaXN1YWwgU3R1ZGlvIDIwMTVcUHJvamVjdHNcSVNPcHNQb3J0YWxWN1xJU09wc1BvcnRhbFY3XFBhdGNoZXNNVkNcQ3JlYXRlXA==?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1872
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=_8qOI5CM8fqapRx5VKYS8KyOSCU2elftgAF-cL1Ex5TXvU_KoeaE177Tg9wjLPCM6lY4FklGoCJzKMZf-dkXSz7BxrGBOd591D9Cdk2syTg1
Host:localhost:59515
Origin:http://localhost:59515
Referer:http://localhost:59515/PatchesMVC/Create
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__RequestVerificationToken"

npYFBwXTvu4ZAtkO7Fu9XGIOHqFDLKuBsy0YuQVVKXERRAucEUSLQsXuhbepOJUMsdncRrY9T2fdBfKb1K4jGd1q_JIDaJ4HQNZg3WC7FzSZQj8hxV7HIpCsXHm_9g9-0
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

MONETT\BiJenkins
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caseID"

123123
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dateofpatch"

08/30/2017 12:00 PM
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ntupdatename"

Test11111
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="esiupdatename"

Test2222
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="addemails"

bijenkins@jackhenry.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="comments"

1234
------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileLocation"; filename="9871255_q12.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed


------WebKitFormBoundaryDLqvIkSdDEsOez7c--
```

**Update 2**

I have tried with prevent default and I get the updateservices field to show up in the request payload but now twice and not as a comma separated value, when it hits the server, I'm still seeing just the first option selected.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your network tab `Post` would be the most helpful.  Providing code that *compiles* for your controller would also be more helpful.

Comment: Added Headers from post.

Comment: Why are you attempting to join the values to a string. Its a `<select multiple>` which posts back an array of values. Your `updateservices` property in the `Patch` model needs to be `IEnumerable<string>` and it will be correctly bound with the values of the selected options. No javascript is required. If your want a csv, do it on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a combination of answers and my own logic.

[Dropdown in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484774/dropdown-in-mvc/10484970#10484970)

[How to MVC 5 drop down (multiple select) box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304543/how-to-mvc-5-drop-down-multiple-select-box)

Since I was entering this using entity framework, I found that you must load the options on the GET view into a `List` of `SelectListItem`'s. You then load the results into a String Array, you then join them all together and add them to the string model field.

This got me working:

Loading in the GET view, I learned to load up a `SelectListItem` field:

```
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    // GET: PatchesMVC/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        ViewBag.userName = userName;

        var vm = new Patch();
        vm.updateservicesSelectedOptions = new List<SelectListItem> {
             new SelectListItem { Value="HCL", Text="HCL" },
             new SelectListItem { Value="HCL2", Text="HCL2" },
             new SelectListItem { Value="HBS", Text="HBS" },
          };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

POST View:

```
    // POST: PatchesMVC/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Patch model)
    {
        model.updateservice = string.Join(",", model.updateservices);
    }
```

Create.cshtml:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="updateservices">Update Services</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.updateservices, Model.updateservicesSelectedOptions)
        </div>
        </div>
```

Model:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Portal.Models
{
    public class Patch
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> updateservicesSelectedOptions { get; set; }
        public string[] updateservices { set; get; }
        public string updateservice { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the form is submitting too fast. You should use `preventDefault` first, and then manually submit after you make the necessary updates to the form data:

```
$('#createform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Combine service update tags
    var tags = $('#updateservices').val().join(',');
    $('#updateservices').attr('value', tags);

    this.submit();
});
```

Although, it would be better overall to handle this server-side with a view model:

```
 public class PathViewModel
 {
     ...
     public List<string> UpdateServices { get; set; } = new List<string>();
 }
```

Then:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(PatchViewModel model)
{
    var patch = new Patch
    {
        // map properties from `model`
        UpdateServices = String.Join(",", model.UpdateServices)
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(patch.updateservices);
}
```

This also has the side-effect of letting you get rid of using `Bind`, which is just awful for many [reasons](https://cpratt.co/bind-is-evil/).

Comment: I am getting `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`. Which then asks as a fix, if I want to add a implicit operator, but it's a generic that doesn't work. Generic: `public static implicit operator Patch(Patch v){throw new NotImplementedException();}` user defined operator cannot take an object of the enclosing type and convert to an object of the closing type`

Comment: When just using e.prevent made the variables show up, but as separate entities in the Request Body. See updated screen shot.